# Lighting Glitch when adding Divisions

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, edges, lighting, loop

[image]

I am having an issue when adding divisions, either through loop cut tool or subdividing, that creates visual glitching. I have smooth shading turned on, and edges marked as sharp. This is not happening on a version of the model with Ngons, which I am cleaning up to be in quads.

Comment: Try maybe to remove custom split normals (Properties editor > Object data tab > Geometry data) and recalculate normals. This appears to be related to normals' vectors

Comment: Hello, have you tried recalculating the normals of the mesh? (Selecting all faces in edit mode -> Shift + N to recalculate). Also, 'removing doubles' if there are faces in the same place (M and clicking on merge by distance).

Comment: Thank you @MrZak , I needed to "Add Custom Split Normals Data"

Comment: @EduardoAbreu Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Object Data Properties > Geometry Data > Add Custom Split Normals